# /api/login_check return 404 not found

Tags: apache, symfony4, lexikjwtauthbundle

I am trying to put my website on production.
For the authentification, I pass by the LexikJWTAuthenticationBundle.

I want to run my website on a Apache server.
Passing by Apache when I run this command:

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" https://mywebsite.com/api/login_check -d '{"username":"admin","password":"admin"}'
```

I get a 404 error.

Meanwhile, If on the same machine I run `symfony server:start`and run this command:

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" https://127.0.0.1:8000/api/login_check -d '{"username":"admin","password":"admin"}'
```

I recieve the requested token.

if I make

> bin/php debug:router

```
api_login_check                                    POST     ANY      ANY    /api/login_check
```

The VHost:

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    <VirtualHost *:443>
    
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
    
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
    
    RewriteEngine on
    ServerName exemple.com
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/.............
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/...............
    Include /etc/..............
    
    <Directory /var/www/html/>
    Allowoverride all
    </Directory>
    #config backOffice intranet 
Alias /backend /var/www/html/backend/public/
    <Directory /var/www/html/backend/public/>
          SetEnv APP_ENV prod
          Require all granted
          AllowOverride all   
          Order Allow,Deny   
          Allow from All 
          Options -MultiViews
          RewriteEngine On
          RewriteBase /backend
          RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
    </Directory>
    
    </VirtualHost>
    </IfModule>
```

security:

```
encoders:
    App\Entity\User:
        algorithm: bcrypt

providers:
    db_users:
        entity:
            class: App\Entity\User
            property: email
    jwt:
        lexik_jwt: ~

firewalls:
    dev:
        pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false
    login:
        provider: db_users
        pattern:  ^/api/login
        stateless: true
        anonymous: true
        json_login:
            username_path: username
            password_path: password
            check_path: /api/login_check
            success_handler: lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_success
            failure_handler: lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_failure
            require_previous_session: false
    api:
        pattern: ^/api
        provider: jwt
        stateless: true
        anonymous: true
        guard:
            authenticators:
                - lexik_jwt_authentication.jwt_token_authenticator
    main:
        anonymous: true

# Easy way to control access for large sections of your site
# Note: Only the *first* access control that matches will be used
access_control:
    - { path: ^/api/login_check, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/api/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/api/health, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/api/user/inscription, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/api/user/test, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/api/user/password/edit, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/api, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY }

role_hierarchy:
    ROLE_USER: ROLE_USER
    ROLE_ADMIN: ROLE_ADMIN
```

I am bit lost, tell me if you need more info.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    <VirtualHost *:443>
    
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/backend/public
    
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
    
    RewriteEngine on
    ServerName exemple.com
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/.............
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/...............
    Include /etc/..............
    
    <Directory /var/www/html/>
    Allowoverride all
    </Directory>
    #config backOffice intranet 
Alias /backend /var/www/html/backend/public/
    <Directory /var/www/html/backend/public/>
          SetEnv APP_ENV prod
          Require all granted
          AllowOverride all   
          Order Allow,Deny   
          Allow from All 
          Options -MultiViews
          RewriteEngine On
          RewriteBase /backend
          RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
    </Directory>
    
    </VirtualHost>
    </IfModule>
```

- composer require symfony/apache-pack